# What is the use of return statement when using with LiveData

Tags: android, performance, viewmodel, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel

I have followed [this](https://github.com/Vishulucky/VIEWMODLECLASS) example, an integrated `ViewModel` and `LiveData`.

I used `LiveData` for `ViewModel` to `Repository` communication, and `activity` to `ViewModel` communication

I have few confusions that I want to clear this question.

This is working fine, and display Toast Message after 5 seconds on MainActivity.

**MainActivity**

```
    MainViewModel homeViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel.class);

    homeViewModel.getResponseval().observe(this, new Observer<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "MainActivityObserverCalled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

**MainViewModel**

```
public class MainViewModel extends ViewModel {

    public MutableLiveData<String> responseval;
    private LoginRepositry loginRepositry;

    public MainViewModel(){
        loginRepositry = new LoginRepositry();
        responseval = loginRepositry.getData("username","password");
    }


    public MutableLiveData<String> getResponseval() {
        return responseval;
    }
```

**LoginRepositry**

```
public class LoginRepositry {

    private MutableLiveData<String> data = new MutableLiveData<>();

    public  MutableLiveData<String> getData(String username , String userpass) {

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                data.setValue("Login Repo Set Value");

            }
        }, 5000);

        return data;
    }
```

These are my 2 questions.

- Now with each method, I am returning some data of type `LiveData`, but
  at the time of returning the data, the value is not set. I set it after 5
  seconds `data.setValue("SomeValue")`, So what is the use of `return`
  here, is it only because of method return type, and does nothing in
  case of `LiveData`
- In  `MainActivity`, i used `homeViewModel.getResponseval().observe`
  to observer data, but in `ViewModel`, I didn't use `observe`, but
  ViewModel is still observing the `Repository` and after 5 seconds
  MainActivity gets a result. I am unable to understand whats happening here
  .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So let's do this by parts:

> Now with each method i am returning some data of type LiveData, but at
>   the time of returning the data, the value is not set. I set it after 5
>   seconds data.setValue("SomeValue"), So what is the use of return here,
>   is it only because of method return type, and does nothing in case of
>   LiveData

If you check the [docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata) you'll see that LiveData "is an observable data holder class", so it holds data and you can observer it. This is very important to understand why you're returning this LiveData object here. By returning it you're telling the next layer of your architecture (the ViewModel) "hey, here is this holder, I will put some data here at some point, so *observer* it if you want to receive the data".

The ViewModel doesn't observe it, but simply pass it to the next entity interested in this holder of data, the UI (`LifeCycleOwner`). So in the owner you start to observe this "holder of data" and will be warned when new data arrives.

> In  MainActivity, i used homeViewModel.getResponseval().observe to
>   observer data, but in  ViewModel, I didn't use observe, but ViewModel
>   is still observing the Repository, and after 5 seconds MainActivity
>   gets result. I am unable to understand whats happening here.

You need a `LifeCycleOwner` in order to observe updates from a `LiveData`, also from the docs: "`LiveData` considers an observer, which is represented by the Observer class, to be in an active state if its lifecycle is in the STARTED or RESUMED state. LiveData only notifies active observers about updates." In order to detect the state, it needs a `LifeCycleOwner`, that's why when you have the `observe` method you pass `this` as a parameter. And that's why you didn't use `observe` in the `ViewModel`.

Comment: One more question, Let say if there are 10 function in `ViewModel` that i need to observe, then I will use `observer(this,..) ` for all of them?

Comment: In theory yes, but the structure of your code shouldn't allow for that. Normally in an Activity you want to keep the Single Responsibility principle, so it doesn't make much sense to have 10 different types of LiveData to observe if your activity should have one single responsibility. :)

Comment: On MainActivity, i do these tasks, `sendUserLocationServer, getNewsFromServer, getEventsFromServer, checkIfPromoIsAvailable,  sendFCMTokenToServer, getJWTToken from server` so for all of these i will create a separate observer `observer(this,..)`

Comment: Yep, if you're returning LiveData you need to observer to get the values